# Jquery - adding number to each iteration starting from 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add numbers starting from 1 to each element added in my loop.

This is the code:

```
function(data, status){
   var cleanData = $.parseJSON(data);
   var i = 1;
   $.each(cleanData, function(key, value, i) {
      $( "#list" ).append(
        "<div class='large-12 columns'><div class='large-1 columns'>" + (++i) + "</div><div class='large-10 columns'><p> " + value.title + "</p></div><div class='large-1 columns'>" + value.count +"</div></div>" );
        });
    }
```

I have also tried it with `(i+1)` but then I get `NaN`

So, that the end result would be something like this:

```
1 title           count
2 someOtherTitle  count 
3 anotherTitle    count
```

Comment: What's your current result? What problem do you need help solving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm not entirely sure what is wrong but maybe try removing i from the function parameters as it's within scope anyways. Also use i++(read then increment) or set i = 0. Otherwise you'll be starting at 2.

```
function(data, status){
   var cleanData = $.parseJSON(data);
   var i = 0;
   $.each(cleanData, function(key, value) {
      $( "#list" ).append(
        "<div class='large-12 columns'><div class='large-1 columns'>" + (i++) + "</div><div class='large-10 columns'><p> " + value.title + "</p></div><div class='large-1 columns'>" + value.count +"</div></div>" );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `cleanData` is a list, use `$.each()` like this

```
$.each(cleanData, function(key, value) {
    ...
    ...ns'>" + (key + 1) + "</di...
```

Comment: I get NaN when I do it like this

Comment: Updated my answer, but @Jinjubei's is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function(data, status){
  var cleanData = $.parseJSON(data);
  var i = 1;
  $.each(cleanData, function(key, value, i) {
  $( "#list" ).append("<div class='large-12 columns'>
  <div class='large-1 columns'>" + i + "</div>
  <div class='large-10 columns'>
  <p> " + value.title + "</p>
  </div>
  <div class='large-1 columns'>" + value.count +"</div>
  </div>" );
    i = i + 1;
    });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function(data, status){
   var cleanData = $.parseJSON(data);
    for(var i=0 ; i < cleanData.length ; i++){
      $( "#list" ).append(
        "<div class='large-12 columns'><div class='large-1 columns'>" + (i+1) + "</div><div class='large-10 columns'><p> " + data[i]['title'] + "</p></div><div class='large-1 columns'>" + data[i]['count'] +"</div></div>" );
      }
    }
```